# Making custom blocks responsive

Tags: theme, rwd, media

I'm using a responsive Magento theme but when I'm making a div or html block through Magento back-end it isn't responsive. I can hardcode it with mediaqueries but what is the easiest and quickest way to do it? because there is 20392013 different mobile screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to install the web developer extension for your browser, then go to your theme online demo and through the above extension choose view responsible layouts. Then inspect the element that it does not appear well and make the changes in the css file of that element.
The `magento` has four css files for mobile devices:
mobile.css
mobile-widescreen.css
tablet.css
tablet-widescreen.css

If you make the changes in those files then your static block would be responsive too.

Answer (score 0):

If its boostrap, you can do the html simply by refering , http://getbootstrap.com/css/.

If we followe this, we can simple make any html responsive. Certain attributes need to add together with html. Its so simple and effective.

You can also use firebug to check in firefox